# bad symbolic reference to org.apache.spark.internal encountered in class file 'KafkaUtils.class'

Tags: maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

I have been writing code on IntelliJ for running "DirectKafkaWordCount.scala"
the source is from apache/spark of Github (spark/example/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/DirectKafkaWordCount.scala) as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._

object KafkaWordCountTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels()

    val brokers = "localhost:2181"
    val topics = "test1"

    // Create context with 2 second batch interval
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCountTest")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
    val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)
    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
      ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams))

    // Get the lines, split them into words, count the words and print
    val lines = messages.map(_.value)
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1L)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
    wordCounts.print()

    // Start the computation
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Also,
I added dependencies to pom.xml as below:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But, I got an error message.

Error:(43,31) bad symbolic reference to org.apache.spark.internal encountered in class file 'KafkaUtils.class'. Cannot access term internal in package org.apache.spark. The current classpath may be missing a definition for org.apache.spark.internal, or KafkaUtils.class may have been compiled against a version that's incompatible with the one found on the current path. 
val message = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](

And I unzipped "spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4" and "spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7" on Desktop folder. each spark is running well on the terminal using spark-shell command. I originally installed Spark version 2.2.0. And, to run the Kafka Direct example, I installed Spark 1.5.2 additionally. Is this a problem?

How this can be resolved?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an issue with incompatible/missing dependencies. Have you tried to build it by Maven from command line?